# Converting CruiseControl to Hudson

Tags: perl, groovy, module, hudson, maven

I am currently writing a Perl script that will convert [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) `config.xml` files to a [Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson) `config.xml` for each project. However I am stuck at one key part: How do I make it so the sub modules of a project also get the goals from there CC config?

I can do the root module fine, and set up the configurations fine as well. I just need a way to configure Hudson to add the sub modules, copy the goals from a file, import the goals, then run the build for the module. The way I am thinking right now is that I could either:

1. Make a Perl script that runs before the build or
2. Make a groovy script that integrates with Hudson and have it manually do these steps.

Side Note: If anyone is interested about using this script I would be willing to publish it once it is done.

Comment: I admire your dedication. I'm just curious why you need such a script? Is it a one-time usage or something you will continually need to use?

Comment: Its just one time usage but I dont want to manually set up 3500+ projects either. So I am trying to automate the process of moving this over.

Comment: do you mind if i ask why you have so many projects? seems quite extreme.

Comment: Its what happens when you manage 14 dev teams for a corporation.

Comment: I'll be very curious to hear about your experience. I assume you're taking advantage of the project preconfiguration features in CruiseControl and I'd love to know how those translate into Hudson.

Comment: @Jeff, I can do the root modules fine its just the sub modules and there configurations that make it more difficult to do. Yea this feature in cruisecontrol is having a hard time for me to move over to hudson. It is really the only road block I am having.

Comment: Is there any way to make this script available to the "unwashed masses"?  :-)

Comment: Hey Nick, I will be glad to put it out there once we move our system over. It has gone on the backburner as of right now. :(

Answer (score 1):

So I beleive I figured out my own problem. Essentially what I am going to do is have every module set to clean, I will add a text file with what module has what goals then add the goals section to the config.xml.Then reload hudson from the disk so it can add the goals then re run the job with the proper goals for the sub job. I did this via perl.